# Question about the boundedness of the following sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know whether the following sequence grows without bounds.

For any small real $b < 1$,
define a sequence $a_n= \frac {(2n)!}{n!}b^n$

It seems to me that the factorial is so large that the above sequence diverges, but how do I prove it rigorously?

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Note that $$\frac{(2n)!}{n!}=\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n}k>n^n\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $b>0$, 
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>b\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{n+1}>1
$$
for large $n$. For $b<0$ similarly, but for $b=0$ the sequence is certainly constant.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Using this theorem might help:

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two sequences of real numbers and suppose that $x_n\le y_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ then

1. if $\lim (x_n)=+\infty$, then $\lim(y_n)=+\infty$
2. If $\lim (y_n)=-\infty$, then $\lim(x_n)=-\infty$

You should be interested in (1). Letting $(a_n)=(y_n)$ try to find a sequence $(x_n)$ that diverges to infinity such that $x_n\le y_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.